# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2AS400DataStoreHelper

Tags: db2, websphere, datasource, adaptor

I am trying to migrate an application from Websphere to Tomcat and facing an issue.

> Class not found: com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2AS400DataStoreHelper

I have this jar **com.ibm.ws.runtime-8.5.5.1** in the lib, but it doesn't have this particular **DB2AS400DataStoreHelper** class inside **rsadapter** package.

I want to find out the jar or the version number which has **DB2AS400DataStoreHelper** class.

```
4:23:42 PM: Caused by: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.exceptions.DataStoreAdapterException: DSRA8050W: Unable to find the DataStoreHelper class specified: com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2AS400DataStoreHelper
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.createDataStoreAdapterException(AdapterUtil.java:441)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigHelper.createDataStoreHelper(DSConfigHelper.java:797)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.<init>(WSRdbDataSource.java:1153)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.setDataSourceProperties(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:2644)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2AS400DataStoreHelper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:119)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? When you say you want "help with the jar", what help do you want? Are you looking for the name of this jar?

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for the jar that has this class.

Comment: Instead of migrating to Tomcat, which will be very problematic, as Tomcat is just web container, migrate to Open Liberty (https://openliberty.io/), which is open sourced version of WebSphere Liberty, a lightweight server. It is much more compatible with WAS than Tomcat, and your migration will be much easier and faster.

Comment: The organisation that I'm working for, decided to move to Tomcat. I have no choice now :D